# Link_to 'xyz: @xyz.size', @xyz Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make it so that this line here:

```
<%= link_to 'Projects: @projects.size', '#', class: 'btn btn-md btn-primary btd' %>
```

Will create a button that has the text 'Projects: ' and then the number of projects that there are currently in the database for this user.

Also because of this, does it mean I would use something similar to

```
@projects.size.where(:user_id == current_user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead: `"Projects: #{@projects.size}"`  (note the double quotes)

You used a plain-old string, and it was literally writing out `Projects: @projects.size` when you really wanted an interpreted string (using double quotes) and the special `#{}` syntax that actually evaluates the code inside.

For projects belonging to the current-user. I'd recommend something like this:

`current_user.projects.count`

Comment: ahh i see i tried this but with single quotes instead of double. what about only displaying for the current user?

Comment: what happens when you do the code you wrote in the rails console? Does it fetch the ones you want? Can you instead use: `current_user.projects.count` ?

Comment: that worked beautifully! Thanks (ill accept your answer when it lets me)